# Removing objects from a list that don't appear in a list of ID's

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of objects with each of them having an ID. I have a second list that is just a list of media ID's. I want to remove the objects from the first list that don't match a mediaID contained in the second list. What is an efficient way of going about this? The only way I could think of was to have a nested for loop but that seems inefficient.

Here is my implementation. Note that "items" is the first list, containing MediaDetailsItem objects, with each of these objects having a specific mediaId. The second list is mediaIds.

```
List<MediaDetailsItem> shortenedList = new ArrayList<MediaDetailsItem>();
                        for(MediaDetailsItem item : items){
                            for(String id : mediaIds){
                                if(item.getMediaId().equals(id)){
                                    shortenedList.add(item);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        items.clear();
                        items.addAll(shortenedList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `for (String id : mediaIds) { ... }` loop iterates over all the entries of `mediaIds`, this is inefficient, a linear search, for each item in `items`. The overall time-complexity of this approach is \$O(n^2)\$.

What is the type of `mediaIds`?
If it's a `Set`, then you could replace the entire inner loop with a simple conditional a call to `mediaIds.contains(...)`:

```
for (MediaDetailsItem item : items) {
  if (mediaIds.contains(item.getMediaId())) {
    shortenedList.add(item);
  }
}
```

This will improve the time-complexity to \$O(n)\$.

If the type of `mediaIds` is not a `Set`, you could build one:

```
Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>(mediaIds);
```

And then adjust the condition: `ids.contains(item.getMediaId())`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without external iteration, if you are using java-8:

```
items.removeIf(item -> !mediaIds.contains(item.getMediaId()));
```

It's not necessary to create a new list, this will modify the existing one.

Comment: Wouldn't list search still be \$O(n)\$ over \$n\$ items, giving \$O(n^2)\$